# Best way to create feed post like this app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, feed

Last week i started learning java/Android Studio.

1. I succeeded to create an app that can upload and download Text in my
   DB (with php,json and sql).
2. But I don't know how to make it like the classic social apps , that
   generate news and posts feed.
3. I searched and found many tools, don't know which one should I use
   to have the exact result** that I want : Recyclerview, listview,
   cardview...

**I want to have this exact result** :

- Textviews with different background color.
- Load 5 Textview. Scrolling down to load more from the DB online.
- Clicking on a Textviews will open a new window (Activity) so that the user can comment ect...

This is an exact exemple of an application that I want to create, how do you think that they did that?

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to base yourself on RecyclerView to dynamically change those "Cards" 
And if you want to add an ImageView within those "Cards", use a CardView to do it. That's pretty much what you need.

To further answer your question, you can have a random color generator in order to dynamically create those "Cards".

Oh and this is what I meant by a "Card".
[Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0gPy.png)

Comment: Thank you for your response ! I will try that.